How to get a list of documents from Cloud Firestore using dart cloud_firestore package
I made a function to read a the data from a specific document and it works(code below)
Future<List<String>> getAllServicesFromDatabase()async{
  List<String> services = [];
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> results = await db.collection(dbCollection).doc(servicesDocument).get();
  if(results.data() != null){
    Map<String,dynamic> fetchedData = results.data()!;
    for(String service in fetchedData.keys.toList()){
      services.add(service);
    }
  }
  return services;
}

Table belonging to the first code sample:

Now I'd like something similar but this time I don't know the name of the documents. I'd like to create a Function that returns a Lists of document names so that I can then Read each individual document.
(my failed attempt below)
class Customer {
  Customer({
    required this.document,
    required this.customer,
  });
  final String document;
  final Map<String,dynamic> customer;
}
Future<List<Customer>> getAllCustomersFromDatabase()async{
  List<Customer> customers = [];
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> response = await db.collection(customersCollection).get();
  response.docs.map((doc){
    String docName = doc.id;
    Map<String, dynamic> document = doc.data();
    Customer customer = Customer(
      document: docName,
      customer: document,
    );
    print(customer.document);
    print(customer.customer);
  });
  return customers;
}

Table belonging to the second code sample:


What do you mean by "failed attempt"? What is the expected result from running the code and what are you getting right now?

Problem:
The current code is mapping over the response.docs and creating a Customer object on each run but not doing anything with either the created Customer object or the result of the map:
response.docs.map((doc){
    String docName = doc.id;
    Map<String, dynamic> document = doc.data();
    Customer customer = Customer(
      document: docName,
      customer: document,
    );
    print(customer.document);
    print(customer.customer);
  });

Solution:
To fix this, do the following:

Return the created Customer object at the end of the map block.
Assign the result of the mapping to the customers variable.

Like this:
customers = response.docs.map((doc){  /// Modified this line
    String docName = doc.id;
    Map<String, dynamic> document = doc.data();
    Customer customer = Customer(
      document: docName,
      customer: document,
    );
    print(customer.document);
    print(customer.customer);

    return customer;   /// Added this line
  });


I appreciate the answer but I already knew that. My question is Why are the print statements not printing what I want. How do I actually get Firebase to provide me such data.

Why the Firebase code doesn't work?

This seems to work
class Customer {
  Customer({
    required this.document,
    required this.customer,
  });
  final String document;
  final Map<String,dynamic> customer;
}
Future<List<Customer>> getAllCustomersFromDatabase()async{
  List<Customer> customers = [];
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> response = await db.collection(customersCollection).get();
  //print("-----------------${response.docs.length}");
  for(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc in response.docs){
    String docName = doc.id;
    Map<String, dynamic> document = doc.data();
    Customer customer = Customer(
      document: docName,
      customer: document,
    );
    customers.add(customer);
  }
  return customers;
}

Firestore rules:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /{path=**}/customers/{document} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

